# Clear fix problems with overflow and pie-clearfix

Tags: css, css-float, clearfix

I am trying to float some elements and apply clearfix so that the parent element can expand to the height and width of the children.

So, I simply set up the layout as per this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fMjEx/

I then wanted to float the elements inside `.bar`. This is usually quite straight forward:

1. Float the elements.
2. Clear fix the parent using `pie-clearfix` or `overflow: auto`.

However, I ran into these problems:

- If I use pie-clearfix, the element `.picture` which is next to `.bar` is also included in the clearing: http://jsfiddle.net/6C7WD/
- If I use `overflow: auto` or `overflow: hidden`, the width of the `.bar` no longer spans the width of the document: http://jsfiddle.net/fv2gA/

Initially, one solution I had was to make `.picture` `position: absolute`. However, the problem with this approach is that the element is taken out of the flow.

In the layout, the height of `.bar` is variable depending on the content inside. I would like to give `.bar` and `.picture` a `margin-bottom` so that anything that comes after them is pushed downwards by that amount depending on whether `.bar` or `.picture` has a greater height.

This rules out using `position: absolute` on `.picture` as a solution.

Are there any solutions that satisfy the following?

- Clear only floats within `.bar`.
- Does not remove any elements from the flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I ended up with:

Added a wrapper to the markup:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="group"> <-------------------------- This is the wrapper
    <div class="picture"></div>
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="info"> some text goes here</div>
        <div class="buttons">some other content goes here</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.picture{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    background: green;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}

.bar{
    background: blue;
    margin-top: -80px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}

.group{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.group:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.info, .button{
    float: left;
    margin-left: 200px;
}

.container{
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Fiddle of the above: http://jsfiddle.net/c6Lng/